# How to change the number separator of a LineChartSeries with spaces?

Tags: primefaces, jqplot

I would like to change the format of the axis of my graph like this: "1 000 000" and I can't find the solution.

Currently this code allows me to have this format "1,000,000" :

```
Axis y = lineModel.getAxis(AxisType.Y);
y.setTickFormat("%'.0f");
```

I work with Primefaces 6.0

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a **chartExtender**.

**main.js**

```
function chartExtender() {
    this.cfg.axes.yaxis.tickOptions.formatString = "%'#.0f";
    $.jqplot.sprintf.thousandsSeparator = ' ';
}
```

**chart.xhtml**

```
<p:lineChart extender='chartExtender'/>
```